# My Python file is showing as Binary file after saving with Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

I have been using Atom for 1 week. And suddenly today when i was trying to open the project it was showing below screen. Other text editors also failed to open this file.

[image]

What can i do to recover this file?

Comment: Have you tried running `file todo.py` at a shell prompt and see what type of file the system believes this is? It may simply say "data" but if it shows a specific file format, someone may have better advice for you.

Comment: ./app.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `)' @DanLowe

Comment: I don't know what app.py is - your screenshow shows the file as `todo.py`. In any case, I meant literally run the command "`file todo.py`" - the `file` command looks at a file and attempts to tell you what _kind_ of file it is.

Comment: @DanLowe Oh, sorry I renamed the file. However, That command shows: data

Comment: I suppose you could try also `strings app.py` and see if the text-only parts of the file look anything like the original file. It is possible you are seeing some sort of file corruption or a disk failure, but it is very hard to tell from outside your system, unfortunately. You may want to poke around your system and see if there are other files that appear to have become corrupted.

Comment: @DanLowe Thanks for the information. Maybe it is my fault, i did shutdown my system by forcefully. By the way there is nothing readable... :(